# Which resource(s) to use to learn the following syllabus of discrete structures?

Tags: discrete-math, resource-request, computer-science

(YES) - included;
(NO) - explicitly excluded;

as stated from the IOI syllabus(2019);

**5.2 Discrete Structures (DS)**

**DS1. Functions, relations, and sets**

(YES)Functions (surjections, injections, inverses, composition)

(YES) Relations (reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity, equivalence
relations, total/linear order relations, lexicographic order)

(YES) Sets (inclusion/exclusion, complements, Cartesian products, power sets)

(NO) Cardinality and countability (of infinite sets)

**DS2. Basic logic**

(YES) First-order logic

(YES) Logical connectives (incl. their basic properties)

(YES) Truth tables

(YES)Universal and existential quantification(Note: statements should avoid definitions with nested quantifiers whenever possible.)

(YES) Modus ponens and modus tollens

(YES)Normal forms

(NO) Validity

(NO) Limitations of predicate logic

**DS3. Proof techniques**

(YES) Notions of implication, converse, inverse, contrapositive, negation, and contradiction
Direct proofs, proofs by: counterexample, contraposition, contradiction

(YES) Mathematical induction

(YES)Strong induction (also known as complete induction)

(YES)Recursive mathematical definitions (incl. mutually recursive definitions)

**DS4. Basics of counting**

(YES) Counting arguments (sum and product rule, arithmetic and geometric progressions, Fibonacci numbers)

(YES) Permutations and combinations (basic definitions)

(YES)Factorial function, binomial coefficients

(YES) Inclusion-exclusion principle

(YES) Pigeonhole principle

(YES) Pascal’s identity, Binomial theorem

(NO)Solving of recurrence relations

(NO)Burnside lemma

**DS5. Graphs and trees**

(YES)Trees and their basic properties, rooted trees

(YES)Undirected graphs (degree, path, cycle, connectedness,

Euler/Hamilton path/cycle, handshaking lemma)

(YES) Directed graphs (in-degree, out-degree, directed path/cycle, Euler/Hamilton path/cycle)
(YES) Spanning trees

(YES) Traversal strategies

(YES) ‘Decorated’ graphs with edge/node labels, weights, colors

(YES) Multigraphs, graphs with self-loops

(YES) Bipartite graphs

(YES) Planar graphs

(NO)Hypergraphs

(NO)Specific graph classes such as perfect graphs

(NO)Structural parameters such as treewidth and expansion

(NO)Planarity testing

(NO)Finding separators for planar graphs

**DS6. Discrete probability**

Applications where everything is finite (and thus arguments about probability can be easily turned into combinatorial arguments)
are (YES), everything more complicated is (NO)

I am preparing for IOI and want a good discrete structure book/resource to learn the above mentioned subjects.

I am currently taking Pre-Calculus relevant Mathematics in my country. I am in 10th grade, India.

I have searched for courses and books but I don't how to find a good one.

Any recommendations and edits are welcome.

Comment: I'm using the Levin book. It may not have all the topics. But it's lovely, and it's free. And I will add any topics I need to.  http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi3.html

Comment: It is free and it is great.

Comment: I'm very happy with Rosen, but it's not open/free. I have lecture slides [here](https://danielrcollins.commons.gc.cuny.edu/teaching/).

Comment: @DanielR.Collins you teach discrete mathematics right?

Comment: @NeeleshV: Yes, I do.